# Computer suddenly became slow?

Tags: linux, performance, fedora

I am using Fedora OS on my Desktop. Normally, I always leave my computer on and access with teamviewer remotely. Last week my computer was on for 7 days, and after I start using it I have discovered it is extremely slow. I tried to reboot few times, but that didn't help me. I also saw that virtuoso-t was using 100% cpu from time to time, and I have removed nepomukserver.desktop from /usr/share/autostart and then reboot. For a few hours I could work normally, but then computer become slow again. There was also process teamviewerd that was constantly running in the background, but killing it didn't help.
How can I identify this sudden problem and see why my computer becomes so slow?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried running `top`?

Comment: Yes. Then I discovered that virtuoso-t and teamviewerd use constantly cpu, but after I remove them, the problem is still present.